# ASP.NET Quits Post and Not executing Button methods

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird state going on, I hope someone can help me understand.  It doesn't seem to be a problem on my local machine.  I can't reproduce it at all.  Once I publish it to GoDaddy, it works fine for about 10 or so attempts, then quits posting during a search results.  I go into the Dev Tools and this is what I see when it's working.

**Successful Request Header**

```
POST /sms.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.anywaymessaging.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1175
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://accounts.anywaymessaging.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://accounts.anywaymessaging.com/sms.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=oxaywle1ttxshxlhz4213dqa; AnywayMsg=SessionID=4DC189DB-639F-4F15-9580-F4E197C6055E
```

**Successful Form Data**

```
__VIEWSTATE=%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%2ByVg%3D%3D
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=61D54015
__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAA3KY8iwC3SchtZa%2BhJ4vk3sZOgphDZcmnB6pJJ9qOUdhtfo3CKncsZOLGA4BvQGNRW6kLP4RbHpuFuwcTwWrQR81fh%2FXUFTtgMJaT8st%2Bn4LS8kePrLELX5WILj4FxliYJ1DTTEYS7ThpqL1ZXnH3qp793UO%2FrU2b3F%2BSVypjznlZJgraocwhIDauR3EkJNTnSKSiBcH244dTFtoKqbmNy9KOC6pxPTO3V2NoAkWjGKEINeivoCAKq90z1IaAALatXS%2Fva1qZEySGgoEEBy%2FMnRwdfH5f%2B2PnNQu1OPtJpRlUe%2FKw5rOkGskk3QcRPLQRw%3D
ctl00%24MainContent%24SearchType=First+Name
ctl00%24MainContent%24SearchFor=Gavin
ctl00%24MainContent%24SubmitButton=Search
```

**Failed Request Header**

```
POST /SMS.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.anywaymessaging.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 659
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://accounts.anywaymessaging.com
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://accounts.anywaymessaging.com/SMS.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=oxaywle1ttxshxlhz4213dqa; AnywayMsg=SessionID=E6C37891-711F-482C-A8AA-186D1AC81424
```

**Failed Form Data**

```
__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJLTczMjQxMjk5D2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPZBYGAgEPDxYGHgRUZXh0BRpFbnRlciB5b3VyIHNlYXJjaCBjcml0ZXJpYR4IQ3NzQ2xhc3MFDU1lc3NhZ2VTZWFyY2geBF8hU0ICAmRkAg0PDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkAg8PDxYCHwNoZGRkdevr7B%2Fbe77QB0dsrrmhG%2FEUUg8RBwxVImfFq5QsbNY%3D
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=61D54015
__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAit83DFYOYQTsHWSO8TDCY1ZOgphDZcmnB6pJJ9qOUdhtfo3CKncsZOLGA4BvQGNRW6kLP4RbHpuFuwcTwWrQR81fh%2FXUFTtgMJaT8st%2Bn4LS8kePrLELX5WILj4FxliYJ1DTTEYS7ThpqL1ZXnH3qp793UO%2FrU2b3F%2BSVypjznlX1tjd1b5DoWbPIBmwacr1wQ7YlnCXd1W9fI%2FSD%2Ffv4d
ctl00%24MainContent%24SearchType=First+Name
ctl00%24MainContent%24SearchFor=Gavin
ctl00%24MainContent%24SubmitButton=Search
```

As you can see, only the __EVENTVALIDATION part is different.   In the server side code, I made it simple, to verify this wasn't because of some other code and did this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Javascript.ConsoleLog($"Page_Load: {Request.Form}");

    SubmitButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SearchBtn_Click);
}

protected void SearchBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Javascript.ConsoleLog($"SearchBtn_Click: {Request.Form}");
}
```

When it stops working, the SearchBtn is never fired and the Page_Load fires, but with no form data.   Any idea what could possibly be causing this?   At first, I thought it was caching, but I've put all kinds of no caching in the response data and in the HTML itself as meta tags.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.    On and the Javascript.ConsoleLog is just a class I have to help track this problem and allows me to see if the method is being fired or not.

```
using System.Web;

namespace accounts.api
{
    static public class Javascript
    {
        static string scriptTag = "<script type=\"\" language=\"\">{0}</script>";
        static public void ConsoleLog(string message)
        {
            string function = "console.log('{0}');";
            string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
        }

        static public void Alert(string message)
        {
            string function = "alert('{0}');";
            string log = string.Format(GenerateCodeFromFunction(function), message);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log);
        }

        static string GenerateCodeFromFunction(string function)
        {
            return string.Format(scriptTag, function);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GoDaddy does have a lot of glitches (a lot I was also experiencing with it), so you may want to redirect it to another site with the same code.

Comment: Movethis line of code `SubmitButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.SearchBtn_Click);`  from Page_Load event handler to Page_PreInit event handler

Comment: @PankajKapare I have actually created a JavaScript link that does a form.submit to by pass the EventHandler all together and it still posts nothing, once it gets into this state.   I found if I let it set for about 2 minutes, then just hit submit, it's working again.  But will get back into a bad state in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GoDaddy issue..  I found they were using old versions of Framework and was dying after so long.   I had them move me over to new servers and I no longer have the issue.